# Why doesn't XCOPY copy my symbolic link?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, xcopy

I have a folder contain a directory symbolic link, with its structure as following:

```
my-folder
 - sub-directory
 - symbolic link (link to d:\some-folder)
 - file
```

The xcopy command I used is

```
xcopy /e /b /i /h my-folder f:\my-folder
```

It does copy everything to `f:\my-folder`, except the symbolic link, did I miss something simple?

Comment: What happens if you omit `/B` and is there any kind of warning, error or informational message in the output?

Comment: I figured it out, the operation requires admin privilege, I opened a new command line window with "Run as administrator" and it works